# Beam JdbcIO.readAll doesn't seem to return results

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to build pipelines for events with Apache Beam. What I wanted to do is reading streaming data from GCP PubSub and read related metadata from MySQL using the ids in the events, then combine those two streams and write to my clickhouse database.

But JdbcIO.readall() doesn't seem to return its stream. As you can see on the `ClickhousePipeline`, after applying `CoGroupByKey.create()`, I am trying to combine two `PCollection`, but `userMetaData` comes in empty, and `ParDo` that chained right after `UserMetadataEnricher()` hasn't executed too.

In `withRowMapper` on `UserMetadataEnricher`, I added `println()` to chech if it's running, and It worked properly and print the results from my database, however, It doesn't return data to the next pipeline.

I guess the problem is related to `Windowing`, I checked it's working when I tested it without windowing. But, PubSubIO is `Unbounded PCollection`, so I have to apply window to use `JDBCIO.readall()` right? I have no clue to solve this problem. I hope to get an answer soon!

MainPipeline

```kotlin
object MainPipeline {
  @JvmStatic
  fun run(options: MainPipelineOptions) {
    val p = Pipeline.create(options)

    val events = p
      .apply(
        "Read DetailViewEvent PubSub",
        PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.inputSubscription)
      )
      .apply(
        "Extract messages",
        ParseJsons.of(FoodDetailViewEvent::class.java)
          .exceptionsInto(
            TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.strings())
          )
          .exceptionsVia { KV.of(it.element(), it.exception().javaClass.canonicalName) }
      )

    val validEvents =
      events.output().setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(FoodDetailViewEvent::class.java))
    val invalidEvents = events.failures()

    invalidEvents.apply(FailurePipeline(options))
    validEvents.apply(ClickhousePipeline(options))

    p.run().waitUntilFinish()
  }

  @JvmStatic
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory
      .fromArgs(*args)
      .withValidation()
      .`as`(MainPipelineOptions::class.java)

    run(options)
  }
}
```

ClickhousePipeline

```kotlin
class ClickhousePipeline(private val options: MainPipelineOptions) :
  PTransform<PCollection<DetailViewEvent>, PDone>() {

  override fun expand(events: PCollection<DetailViewEvent>): PDone {
    val windowedEvents = events
      .apply(
        "Window", Window
          .into<DetailViewEvent>(GlobalWindows())
          .triggering(
            Repeatedly
              .forever(
                AfterProcessingTime
                  .pastFirstElementInPane()
                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5))
              )
          )
          .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes()
      )

    val userIdDetailViewEvents = windowedEvents
      .apply(
        MapElements.via(object :
          SimpleFunction<DetailViewEvent, KV<String, DetailViewEvent>>() {
          override fun apply(input: DetailViewEvent): KV<String, DetailViewEvent> {
            return KV.of(input.userInfo.userId, input)
          }
        })
      )

    val userMetaData = userIdDetailViewEvents
      .apply(
        MapElements.via(object :
          SimpleFunction<KV<String, DetailViewEvent>, String>() {
          override fun apply(input: KV<String, DetailViewEvent>): String {
            return input.key!!
          }
        })
      )
      .apply(
        UserMetadataEnricher(options)
      )
      .apply(
        ParDo.of(
          object : DoFn<UserMetadata, KV<String, UserMetadata>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            fun processElement(
              @Element data: UserMetadata,
              out: OutputReceiver<KV<String, UserMetadata>>
            ) {
              println("User:: ${data}") // Not printed!!
              out.output(KV.of(data.userId, data))
            }
          })
      )

    val sourceTag = object : TupleTag<DetailViewEvent>() {}
    val userMetadataTag = object : TupleTag<UserMetadata>() {}

    val joinedPipeline: PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> =
      KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(sourceTag, userIdDetailViewEvents)
        .and(userMetadataTag, userMetaData)
        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create())

    val enrichedData = joinedPipeline.apply(
      ParDo.of(object : DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, ClickHouseModel>() {
        @ProcessElement
        fun processElement(
          @Element data: KV<String, CoGbkResult>,
          out: OutputReceiver<ClickHouseModel>
        ) {

          val name = data.key
          val source = data.value.getAll(sourceTag)
          val userMetadataSource = data.value.getAll(userMetadataTag)

          println("==========================")
          for (metadata in userMetadataSource.iterator()) {
            println("Metadata:: $metadata") // This is always empty
          }

          for (event in source.iterator()) {
            println("Event:: $event")
          }
          println("==========================")

          val sourceEvent = source.iterator().next()
          if (userMetadataSource.iterator().hasNext()) {
            val userMetadataEvent = userMetadataSource.iterator().next()
            out.output(
              ClickHouseModel(
                eventType = sourceEvent.eventType,
                userMetadata = userMetadataEvent
              )
            )

          }
        }
      })
    )

    val clickhouseData = enrichedData.apply(
      ParDo.of(object : DoFn<ClickHouseModel, Row>() {
        @ProcessElement
        fun processElement(context: ProcessContext) {
          val data = context.element()
          context.output(
            data.toSchema()
          )
        }
      })
    )

    return clickhouseData
      .setRowSchema(ClickHouseModel.schemaType())
      .apply(
        ClickHouseIO.write(
          "jdbc:clickhouse://127.0.0.1:8123/test?password=example",
          "clickhouse_test"
        )
      )
  }
}
```

UserMetadataEnricher

```kotlin
class UserMetadataEnricher(private val options: MainPipelineOptions) :
  PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<UserMetadata>>() {

  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override fun expand(events: PCollection<String>): PCollection<UserMetadata> {
    return events
      .apply(
        JdbcIO.readAll<String, UserMetadata>()
          .withDataSourceConfiguration(
            JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
              "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/beam-test"
            )
              .withUsername("root")
              .withPassword("example")
          )
          .withQuery("select id,name,gender from user where id = ?")
          .withParameterSetter { id: String, preparedStatement: PreparedStatement ->
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id)
          }
          .withCoder(
            SerializableCoder.of(
              UserMetadata::class.java
            )
          )
          .withRowMapper
          {
            println("RowMapper:: ${it.getString(1)}") // printed!!
            UserMetadata(
              it.getString(1),
              it.getString(2),
              it.getString(3)
            )
          }
      )
  }
}
```

output

```
RowMapper:: test-02
RowMapper:: test-01
==========================
Event:: DetailViewEvent(...)
==========================
==========================
Event:: DetailViewEvent(...)
==========================
```

## Update 1 (GlobalWindow to FixedWindow)

### using AfterProcessing

I've changed my window setting and added print to `SimpleFunction` that is assigned to userIdDetailViewEvents.

```kotlin
Window.into<FoodDetailViewEvent>(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          .triggering(
            Repeatedly.forever(
              AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(
                Duration.standardSeconds(1)
              )
            )
          )
          .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
          .discardingFiredPanes()
      )
```

And It prints:

```sh
userIdDetailViewEvents Called
userIdDetailViewEvents Called
RowMapper:: test-02
RowMapper:: test-01
==========================
Event:: DetailViewEvent(...)
==========================
==========================
Event:: DetailViewEvent(...)
==========================
```

### Using AfterWatermark

```kotlin
        Window.into<FoodDetailViewEvent>(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          .triggering(
            Repeatedly.forever(
              AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
            )
          )
          .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
          .discardingFiredPanes()
```

outputs

```sh
userIdDetailViewEvents Called
userIdDetailViewEvents Called
RowMapper:: test-02
RowMapper:: test-01
```

I think using AfterWatermark is correct but It is hanging on somewhere... I guess It's `JdbcIO`

Comment: But `GlobalWindows()` can be only used when `PCollection` is bounded, I assumed this reading the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-your-pcollections-windowing-function). Am I right?

Comment: Yeah! I realized that using `FixedWindow` is the correct way to achieve this. But the problem is still happening..

Comment: What about using `AfterWatermark`? Does it still return empty records?

Comment: @mk_sta With AfterWatermark, It doesn't return any records, It just hanging on the RowMapper of JdbcIO I guess, I added the code and the result above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the standard configuration doesn't return results with unbounded collections.

As long as you have a functional window / trigger combination the trick is to set
`.withOutputParallelization(false);` to the `JdbcIO.<>readAll()` call as follows:

```
p.apply("Read from JDBC", JdbcIO.<>readAll()
              .withDataSourceConfiguration(getConfiguration())
              .withQuery(getStreamingQuery())
              .withParameterSetter((JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<String>) (element, preparedStatement) -> {
                // Prepare statement here.
              })
              .withRowMapper((JdbcIO.RowMapper<>) results -> {
                // Map results here. 
              }).withOutputParallelization(false));
```

I struggled with this for hours but came across the code [in this article](https://nl.devoteam.com/en/blog-post/querying-jdbc-database-parallel-google-dataflow-apache-beam/) and it finally worked.

I used

```
Window.into(new GlobalWindows()).triggering(
                        Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))
                                )
                                 .discardingFiredPanes())
```

for my trigger to process one element at a time.

Answer (score 2):

`GlobalWindow` never closes so it's not a suitable option for unbounded data source like pubsub.

I would recommend using `FixedWindow(<Some time range>)` instead. 
You can read more about windows here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've changed to `FixedWindow.of(Duration.standardSeconds(120))`. I agree with you that It's better way to do this. However, Metadata still hasn't printed... I don't think It's problem because of triggering, since It prints values without `JdbcIO`.

Comment: I see `==========================` getting printed but the subsequent for loop for printing Metadata is not executed which suggests that `userMetadataSource` might be empty. Can you please validate that this is not the case.

Comment: Yes you are right! `userMetadataSource` is empty, and It's not processed after `RowMapper` in `UserMetadataEnricher`. But according to the outputs above. `RowMapper` has successfully fetched the records and should return them, I don't know why it's not processed after `RowMapper`

The pipeline should clone the `PCollection` into two `PCollection`s, then merge two `PCollection` using the key. I thought It makes sense. Can I achieve this in Beam? or What I wanted to do isn't possible?